# RHEL instances migration(lift and shift) to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, migration

We have a few RHEL 6.3 instances running different applications, and a few RHEL 6.5 instances running SAP HANA workload in our DC at the moment, which we would like to migrate to AWS Mumbai region.

I had a look at the AWS workplace and for Mumbai region I don't find RHEL 6 instances at all in [there](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results/ref=mkt_blg_jb_rhel?page=1&filters=regions&regions=ap-south-1&searchTerms=RHEL%20OSS), and also in Red Hat [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/partners/redhat/faqs/) it is written that SAP has certified RHEL 6.6 for SAP HANA in AWS, so I believe RHEL 6.5 is not certified ?

I wanted to ask is it a good idea to just lift and shift these instances to AWS or should we upgrade the instance's OS during migration?

Any pointers would be appriciated.

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 0):

Hi the mumbai region is too new and the redhat instances 6.5 are too old
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007NMF9O0/ref=mkt_ste_new

You could not find this instances in the mumbai region because of this limitation, the RHEL 6.5 are instances for an old version of the aws instances types t1, m1 family so your options are

You could still use this AMI for Singapore and Sydney but soon o later you will need to upgrade

You could use a newer AMI and install for scratch (Recomended)

Answer (score 0):

Best option for Lift and Shift in this case would be to create a new AMI from scratch, get the correct RHEL version install it and the use RSYNC to copy all files, when you reboot you may check all is working correctly, that is what I would do.